# Injectivity of a function $h:[0,+\infty) \rightarrow [0,+\infty)$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Consider
$$
h(x) = \dfrac{2x^2}{5+1}.
$$

Is $h$ an injective function?

I already tried taking an arbitrary element from the interval $[0,+\infty)$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 3):

If $h(x)=h(y)$ you get $10xy(x-y)=2(y-x)(y+x)$ after some simplification. If $x \neq y$ this gives $10xy+2x+2y=0$. Since $x, y \geq 0$ this is possible only when $x=y=0$ so the function is injective.

Answer (score 3):

$h'(x)=\dfrac{10x^2+4x}{(5x+1)^2}$ is positive for $x>0$,

so $h(x)$ is strictly increasing on the domain, hence injective.